# MySQL Cross Table Query 3 tables, null values display grid

Tags: php, mysql, select, explode

I have three tables in MySQL which connect together to show what qualifications a user has. I want create a table where the headers show the full list of Types, then the left hand column has the username then the columns display the expiry date under the type header like so:

```
Type
========
Type ID (PK, Int)
Type (VarChar)

User
========
User_ID (PK, Int)
Name (VarChar)

Qualification
========
Quali_ID (PK, Int)
User_ID (Int)
Type_ID (Int)
DateExpire (Date)
Status (VarChar)
```

I want to create an output like so:

```
Users  Type1   Type2   Type3   Type4   .......
User1  Qual    Qual            Qual    .......
User2          Qual    Qual            .......
User3                  Qual            .......
User4  Qual    Qual    Qual    Qual    .......
```

Not all the users have every qualifications and it'd be subject to where a qualification status is equal to 'Full' and the expiry date isn't in the past from todays date.

I created some SQL after googling high and low on the internet which is below but I can't get it to include the types that don't exist.

I plan to take the results from the MySQL query in PHP and explode each row to make it populate a table. If someone can help me finish the SQL to make it show the missing Type columns or suggest a better way, I'd be grateful.

My SQL:

```
SELECT 'User_ID', 'Name', GROUP_CONCAT(Types.Title ORDER BY QualiList.Type_ID) AS QualType
FROM TYPES
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Type_ID FROM Qualification) QualiList
ON (QualiList.Type_ID = Types.Type_ID)

UNION ALL

SELECT User.User_ID, User.Name AS Name, GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(Qualification.DateExpire,'NA') ORDER BY QualiList.Type_ID) AS QualType
FROM TYPES
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Type_ID FROM Qualification) QualiList
ON (QualiList.Type_ID = Types.Type_ID)
LEFT JOIN Qualification ON (Qualification.Type_ID = QualiList.Type_ID)
INNER JOIN User ON (User.User_ID = Qualification.User_ID)
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer

```
SELECT USER,
 if(sum(user_id*(1-abs(sign(type_id-1))))>0,DateExpire,'NA') AS TypeADate,
 if(sum(user_id*(1-abs(sign(type_id-1))))>0,Status,'NA') AS TypeAStatus,
 if(sum(user_id*(1-abs(sign(type_id-2))))>0,DateExpire,'NA') AS TypeBDate,
 if(sum(user_id*(1-abs(sign(type_id-2))))>0,Status,'NA') AS TypeBStatus,
 if(sum(user_id*(1-abs(sign(type_id-3))))>0,DateExpire,'NA') AS TypeCDate,
 if(sum(user_id*(1-abs(sign(type_id-3))))>0,Status,'NA') AS TypeCStatus

 FROM (
   SELECT U.USER, T.Type, Q.Type_ID, Q.User_ID,Q.DateExpire,Q.Status FROM Qualification Q
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TYPE T
   ON Q.Type_id = T.ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN USER U
   ON Q.User_id = U.ID
 GROUP BY T.ID, U.ID
 ) xxx GROUP BY USER
```

Check the answer on http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1233/16